# What did Donald Glover mean by "Migos are the Beatles of this Generation"?

Tags: rap, hip-hop

As a fan of hip-hop/rap music I was highly anticipating Migos new album 'Culture' which was released in the last couple of days.

When reading some of the reviews, I noticed there was a reference to Donald Glover (Childish Gambino) declaring them 'the Beatles of this generation'.

What did he mean by this? Why does he think it? Are there any distinct similarities between between a pop group from Liverpool, and a rap trio from Atlanta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Beatles are widely considered the greatest artist of their generation, Glover is saying that Migos is the greatest artist of this generation.

This is actually a pretty common way of comparing artists, albums, etc., and such comparisons even extend beyond music. More examples:

- [NME calls Radiohead the "Beatles of the 21st Century"](http://www.nme.com/blogs/nme-blogs/how-radiohead-became-the-beatles-of-the-21st-century-8751)
- [Chris Martin says Rihanna is the "Frank Sinatra of today"](http://www.justjared.com/2016/06/25/chris-martin-says-rihanna-is-the-frank-sinatra-of-today/)
- [EW asks if Eminem is the "Elvis Presley of today"](http://ew.com/article/2000/12/23/eminem-elvis-presley-today/)
- [Science 20 determines who is the "Einstein of today"](http://www.science20.com/hammock_physicist/who_todays_einstein_exercise_ranking_scientists-75928)
- [Elle asks if Kim Kardashian is the "Marilyn Monroe of today"](http://www.elle.com/fashion/news/a18935/kim-kardashian-marilyn-monroe/)
- [Airbnb CEO says that he referred to company as the "eBay of space"](https://techcrunch.com/2014/09/09/brian-chesky-hotels-and-airbnb-are-the-same-but-different/)
- *[The Room](http://www.popculturecrunch.com/the-worst-movies-of-all-time/)* has been called "*The Godfather* of bad movies"